# Angular 2 Frontend with Active Record Association in Rails 5 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, angular, activerecord

Please help I have an API App in Rails and its huge part is dependent on Active Record Association, I want to understand how to consume relationship between active record models rendered by Rails API on my Angular 2 Frontend Application. For example:

I have a *project.ts* file with

```
export class Project {
  constructor( public id?: number,
    public title?: string, 
    public category_id?: number
  ) {} 
}
```

And a *category.ts* file with

```
export class Category {
  constructor(
   public id?: number, 
   public name?: string
  ) {}
}
```

also a *category.rb* model file with

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
end
```

and a project.rb model file

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :category
end
```

I have been able to implement the communication with the API from the Angular front end.  In a rails view (an erb or haml) file if I want to get the category of a Project, I would do @project.category

With the code structure I have above how can I get the Category name instance of a Project using the category_id that i have in the *project.ts* file? 
How can I have access to the name and all other attribute of the Category, using category_id in the project.ts? since the JSON object rendered will only have the category_id, this example below did not work for me...

```
*ngFor = "let project of projects" 
project.category_id.name
```

any ideas on how to fix this?

I was able to get the category name attribute into the JSON object using ActiveModelSerializer, my object now looks like this.

```
[
   {
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mobile Development"
    },
    "category_id": 1,
    "description": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. \n      It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.",
    "id": 22,
    "title": "Project 9 Test",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-23T05:30:05.098Z"
 },
]
```

When I try to access {{ project.category }} from the front end i get [object Object]
{{ project.category_id }} returns a valid ID, any idea how I can access name attribute? when i tried {{ project.category.name }} it didn't work.

Comment: I tried with this and I got the Category ID, Still can't get the Category name from rails...
    {{ project.category_id }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to working after validating that I got a JSON object on the front end. This is what my category.ts file now looks like. Angular Pipes are very useful, [check here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) to read more about them.

```
export class Category {
  constructor(
  public id?: number, 
  public name?: string
 ) {}
}

let category: Category = JSON.parse('{"id": id, "name": name}');
```

​Had to also validate that category name is available for all projects in the front end also with

```
<small *ngIf="project.category">Category: {{ project.category.name }}</small>​
```

If you are wondering what my ProjectsController index looks like, here it is. Also don't forget to create a category_serializer and project_serializer check ActiveModelSerializer documentation on how to do that.

```
def index
  @projects = Project.order('created_at DESC')
  render json: @projects, include: 'category.name'
end
```